# 403 and 404 error pages Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

```
function multipurpose_zymphonies_theme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
 $header = drupal_get_http_header("status");
  if ($header == "404 Not Found") {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__404';
  }
  elseif ($header == "403 Forbidden") {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__403';
  }
  }
```

> I am using this above code to redirect the 404 and 403 to custom pages
>   but
>
> nothing happens. I have created two files: page--404.tpl.php and
>   page--403.tpl.php in my theme templates folder

if i simply write in the url "http://example.com/readme" then its show 404 which is custommize by me but when i write like "http://example.com/readme.txt" then its show

> Not Found The requested URL "/readme.txt" was not found on this
>   server.

and for other error forbidden access when i write in the url like "http://example.com/%7C~.aspx"

> Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested
>   object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.  If
>   you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.  Error
>   403

I want to handle all these error for custom pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure default error pages  through configuration from the url :

yoursite/admin/config/system/site-information

Administration > Configuration > System >  Site information

Comment: The path 'error-403' is either invalid or you do not have access to it.
The path 'error-404' is either invalid or you do not have access to it.  when i am trying to enter the name of the pages its show the above error